# Tomcat 7 Ciphers For High Security

Tags: tomcat, ssl, tomcat7, tomcat6

I'm migrating to Tomcat 7 and figured it was a good time to review the ciphers I'm using for SSL connections.  I realized I set these up about 5 years ago and never thought about them since.

Is my list missing any important ciphers?  Does it include any I shouldn't?

My web application is one where security is important, so erring on the side of caution is preferred.  Support for IE8 is required, international users as well (but not North Korea).

```
ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version:

- Add TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- Add TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
- Add TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA25
- Drop the 3DES cipher suites if you don't have any XP clients.

The longer explanation:

Cipher suites supported vary from JVM major version to major version and between vendors. Check you JVM docs for the list of supported cipher suites or use something along these lines to list them.

```
package org.apache.markt;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactory;

public class CryptoInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Set<String> algorithms = Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher");
            for(String algorithm: algorithms) {
                int max;
                max = Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(algorithm);
                System.out.printf("%-22s: %dbit%n", algorithm,
                        Integer.valueOf(max));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SSLServerSocketFactory f =
            (SSLServerSocketFactory) SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
        String[] cs = f.getSupportedCipherSuites();
        for (String c : cs) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }

    }
}
```

You probably don't want any of the KRB5 cipher suites so remove those.
You can also remove TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (dummy cipher suite used to indicate if secure renegotiation is supported) if present.
Remove anything that mentions NULL, anon, export or DES as insecure.
RC4 has some issues so you probably want to remove those too.
IE8 doesn't support ECDH so remove those.
IE8 on XP doesn't support ECDHE so you may want to drop those.

Which leaves the list you have above plus:
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256

You should probably think about dropping the 3DES ciphers from the list too. The issue there is IE8 on XP doesn't support AES (IE8 on Vista onwards does). So you might not be able to do that.

You might find these references useful:

http://www.g-sec.lu/sslharden/SSL_comp_report2011.pdf

https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_TLS_Deployment_Best_Practices_1.3.pdf